# Can you hot-plug a USB to TTL Serial Cable to the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio, usb, serial-console

Generally speaking, hot-plugging devices/sensors onto the GPIO pins of a running Pi is a potentially device/Pi damaging bad practice. But does that hold true for a PL2303TA chipset-based USB to TTL Serial Cable?  [Like this.](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954?gclid=Cj0KCQiAtJbTBRDkARIsAIA0a5O2FYlN1o9kSopr2LLfhsfvW-lNFBTnaCkd4ODKdxa2n6tk-lyXNoIaAsQSEALw_wcB)  Since one side is USB, is there some sort of power sequence inherent within USB that might make this a safe practice?

Like maybe plug the GPIO pins first then plug in the USB to my PC.

[image: PI TTL Serial Cable Connection]

The reason that I want this is that, sometimes when my Pi's lose Wi-Fi connectivity, my network detection/restart scripts on the Pi are unsuccessful in restarting the Wi-Fi connection.  This leaves me without a way to log into the Pi.

Comment: USB is hot-pluggable by design. It's not different on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @Janka, as a general StackExchange rule, please do not post answers as comments. As you say hotplugging should work (as per spec) so that should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, provided you are sure it is compatible. Adafruit [sells such an adapter](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954?gclid=Cj0KCQiAtJbTBRDkARIsAIA0a5PYSy4VgQPPBdOxn8rJvV7xgu4QLj47b6b5JSWA4eDj7s88F_F-YNUaAoEMEALw_wcB). From the product description on that page:

> The power pin provides the 5V @ 500mA direct from the USB port and the
>   RX/TX pins are 3.3V level for interfacing with the most common 3.3V
>   logic level chipsets.

Do be careful connecting 5V power. Generally, you want to power the RPi through a separate power supply, not via the USB adapter.

As to specific sequence, I'm not aware of any. I had no issues plugging and replugging into a PC USB port. YMMV.

Comment: I attach one of these FTDI cables to my Raspberry Pi devices all the time.  It's really the only way to debug a live unit that can't connect to the network for some unknown reason.  You just need to make sure that the GPIO serial console is enabled using `raspi-config`.